# Swift - Detect orientation and accordingly do something

Tags: swift

As stated in my subject I need to get my orientation and according to the present orientation i need to do some stuff.

Also when the orientation changes i need to do some layout changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

    if orientation.isLandscape {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
```

and when the device is rotated, you can use this..

```
 override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    if toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: haaa haa no problem, I am new to swift as well. Learning a lot from here so trying to help my fellow rookies ;)